# What happens to the exectuting threads (other than Main thread) of an App when the user presses the "Home" button

Tags: android

As far as I know the main thread or UI thread will be paused the moment user presses "Home" button as it comes under Activity Life cycle. But what happens to the other exectuting threads of an App when the user presses the "Home" button? Does they be executing like background processes or will be paused? If they continue with execution can I say these can be the replacement for Services?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they will continue to run in the background.

Also see this: [Application threads vs Service threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633334/application-threads-vs-service-threads)