# optimal way of doing background opertion in android?

Tags: android

what is the optimal way to run background operation multiple times on different sets of data with only one instance running in the background?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Comment: Create a service and use Firebase JobDispatcher to execute that server at some point in time, or when some conditions are met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of WorkManager architecture component to achieve it. Schedule a `PeriodicWorkRequest` as follows:

**Create Worker class:**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {

        // Do the work here

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

**Schedule the Work:**

```
  PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new 
  PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                   .build();
  WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWork);
```

This creates a PeriodicWorkRequest to run periodically once every 12 hours.

You can check out my answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343578/android-work-manager-vs-services/50373395#50373395) which describes if WorkManager is appropriate for your use-case.

The minimum supported API is 14.

**Based on the documentation:**

> - WorkManger uses JobScheduler for API 23+
> - For API 14-22
>
>   - If using Firebase JobDispatcher in the app and the optional Firebase
>       dependency, uses Firebase JobDispatcher
>   - Otherwise, uses a custom
>       AlarmManager + BroadcastReceiver implementation

Comment: Please mention API support from

Comment: @RanjithKumar Updated the information