# Trigger function at 1 hour interval

Tags: android, android-studio

I create an android application with android studio and I wish to **trigger a function in the interval of 1 hours**. When the function is trigger I need to **call a asp file by URL** and check the database with this asp file. If is there any **available record return from asp file**, then I **trigger the notification**, if there is no record exists, my application do nothing.

Letter that I bold in above is the function I wish to achieve.
Anyone know how to achieve this in a simple method ??

Please do let me know if there is anything unclear.

Thanks !!

Comment: have you check my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732213/optimal-way-of-doing-background-opertion-in-android/50732277#50732277) ?

Comment: Thanks, but I found it out. I used Alarm Manager to help me done the job and it run smoothly.

Comment: Have you tested it on Android O with doze mode restriction?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Still under progress. Thanks for your information !

Comment: Standard Alarms won't fire during Doze mode and also you cannot start background Services from Android O. It will give `IllegalStateException` and could crash your app