# Why android has various types of service and is workManager an alternative to services

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-service-binding

I'm learning Android and currently, I am dealing with the background stuff and came to know about two things services and workManager. Before I got started with any of the ones I got to know about different types of services like "Services, IntentServices, ForegroundServices, BoundServices, and JobIntentServices". Please differentiate between them what are for and when to use them. Also, is Services deprecated because "WorkManager" also does the same thing according to their documents?

Comment: You should be able to answer these questions by reviewing the documentation on each item. If not, could you be a bit more specific in what you're looking for or what you're confused about?

Comment: I'm confused with workManager and Services class. Do workManager and Services intend to perform the same task?
Do I need to learn Services or workmanager alone is enough for not so complex projects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Work Manager vs Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343578/android-work-manager-vs-services)